# How could I build a plugin that provides a socketio endpoint

Tags: python, python-socketio

I got a existing software project, that has a relatively primitive plugin system and wanted to expand it by providing a web interface.

Since my application processes realtime data, websockets are the only option besides web rtc.

My previous attempt used zeromq domain sockets on the python side and a server in Node js that connected to the domain socket.
This solution works great and has some benefits over the plugin server, but I want to offer a simpler option for folks that don't need the benefits and don't want the extra complexity.

How would you go about implementing this and is it even possible to do so?
Otherwise, I'll still do a separate process, but use fastapi to build the stuff around the socket endpoint and start it up using subprocess to spawn a second process that also connects to the domain socket.
Hope my question is not stupid, or a rtfm case.

Comment: Can you be more specific? there is a python web-rtc module called `aiortc` for rtc and that may or may not be useful.

Comment: I would prefer using socket.io and webrtc would only be my fallback. So I did not look too deep into it